# Setting path to java_home

Tags: command-line, bash, java, environment-variables

I am a beginner to Java as well as to Ubuntu.

I downloaded JDK 10.0.2 zip file and unzipped using tar command.

I used vim .bashrc and typed the following

```
export JAVA_HOME=path of my Java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
source .bashrc
```

`echo $JAVA_HOME` and `echo $PATH` giving the correct path of my Java 10.0.2

I am able to compile the file using the javac command and .class file created successfully.

When I am running java ( java ./Desktop/app/Numbers) referring to the class file, I am not able to run and getting the "Main class not found exception"

But, when I go to that particular folder and execute the javac as well as java, I am getting the output.

## What I have tried

1)  `vim .bashrc` and typed the above. But it didn't work.

2) `sudo vim ./etc/environment` and tried adding within the quotes `:/javapath/bin"`. It didn't work.

Guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Use `~/Desktop/app/Numbers` instead! You seem to have a `dot` before that path

Comment: I tried java ~/Desktop/app/Numbers and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok run that command like this:

```
java -classpath /home/$USER/Desktop/app Numbers
```

Since your running it from another location java expects this format:

```
java -classpath /path/to/class/file class_file_name
```

**NOTE**: The space between path and class file name. See `java -help` or `man java`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I typed java -cp (classpath too working) ./Desktop/app Numbers. Do I need to run this every time when I run the program ? Is this the same for running jar file as well ?

Comment: Yes I believe so `-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>` run `java -help` to see more and please kindly accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Comment: Being a new user, I am not able to check the mark as it's asking to wait for 15 mins.

Comment: That's fine return to do that then, cheers!